# Wifi Hotspot that requires a Facebook 'Like' to connect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, wifi

I'm setting up a free Wifi hotspot that guests can use. I would like them to have to 'Like' the company's Facebook page to get Wifi access. Facebook DOES provide "Check in to use Wifi", but since we are not a shop/restaurant etc. I would like for the user to "like" the page instead. I know that this question has been asked on SO a couple of times, but there seems to be no solution yet. I know there are companies that provide this service for really high charges, so it is possible, but since I'm a web dev, I would like to do it myself! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if I wanted to use the Wi-Fi but I didn't really like the company? What about people without facebook accounts? (Think: Senior Corporate Execs in my experience). Facebook as the world's authentication portal cannot be a good thing! /rant :-)

Comment: Like gating is not allowed.

Comment: Well there are numerous of official services that offer this product so it's probably not illegal. And let me state that the whole reason we want to set up our Wifi like this is to generate 'likes'. We have another wifi network for employees etc. so it's just something extra we are providing. If somehow you are in the vicinity of our company and you don't 'like' us for some reason, well then just not use our wifi. I don't see how we should be obligated to give everybody free access to our wifi? This way people that 'like' our company get free wifi, and we get an extra like on our page?

Answer (score 1):

This "like-gating" via the SignedRequest functionality will stop working on November 6th 2014,  as stated in the official docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1_90_day_deprecations

> The 'liked' property will no longer be returned in the 'signed_request' object for Page Tab apps created after today. From November 5, 2014 onwards, the 'liked' property will always return 'true' regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.